# How to Map Two Tables To One Class in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am having a problem with fluent nhiberbate mapping two tables to one class.

I have the following database schema:

```
TABLE dbo.LocationName
(
  LocationId INT PRIMARY KEY,
  LanguageId INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(200)
)

TABLE dbo.Language
(
  LanguageId INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Locale CHAR(5)
)
```

And want to build the following class definition:

```
public class LocationName 
{
      public virtual int LocationId { get; private set; }
      public virtual int LanguageId { get; private set; }
      public virtual string Name { get; set; }
      public virtual string Locale { get; set; } 
}
```

Here is my mapping class:

```
  public LocalisedNameMap()
  {
     WithTable("LocationName");
     UseCompositeId()
        .WithKeyProperty(x => x.LanguageId)
        .WithKeyProperty(x => x.LocationId);
     Map(x => x.Name);

     WithTable("Language", lang =>
                             {
                                lang.WithKeyColumn("LanguageId");
                                lang.Map(x => x.Locale);
                             });
  }
```

The problem is with the mapping of the Locale field being from another table, and in particular that the keys between those tables don't match. Whenever I run the application with this mapping I get the following error on startup:

> Foreign key
>   (FK7FC009CCEEA10EEE:Language
>   [LanguageId])) must have same number
>   of columns as the referenced primary
>   key (LocationName [LanguageId,
>   LocationId])

How do I tell nHibernate to map from LocationName to Language using only the LanguageId field?

Comment: You're trying to denormalize your data in the objects...I just don't think it's going to happen, and it kinda defeats the purpose of ORM. You could always denormalize your tables, I guess.

Comment: Do you really want that in **one** class, or would it be acceptable to have a `LocationName` class and a `Language` class? In which case you can map the relationship with the `References()` method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to change the WithKeyProperty(x => x.LanguageId) to WithKeyReference(x => x.LanguageId).
I haven't used fluent in years and moved to the internal mapping by code.  But the gist is that you you need to make part of that PK a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use , don't know the name in FNH, to denormalize a class, that is, bring in a column from another table. See http://ayende.com/blog/3961/nhibernate-mapping-join

Comment: You can use "join", I mean.